# $\oint \ \frac{ \zeta'(z)} {\zeta(z)}dz$ should give number of zeroes of $ \zeta(s)$ times $2\pi i$ but, due to some reasons, it isn't.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, riemann-zeta

Basically, if we integrate $\oint \ \frac{ \zeta'(z)} {\zeta(z)}dz$ over a rectangle of vertices, say (1+15i), (0+15i), (0+10i) and (1+10i) (counter-clockwise), then, according to Cauchy's Residue Theorem, it should give us number of zeroes of the Riemann zeta function in that rectangle times $2\pi i$ (as there aren't any poles in that region) which is, in fact, just $2\pi i$. However, if the integral $\oint \ \frac{ \zeta'(z)} {\zeta(z)}dz$ is integrated individually on each line of the rectancle, i.e $\int_{1}^0 \frac{ \zeta'(x+15i)} {\zeta(x+15i)}dx+i\int_{15}^{10} \frac{ \zeta'(iy)} {\zeta(iy)}dy+\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ \zeta'(x+i10)} {\zeta(x+i10)}dx+i\int_{10}^{15} \frac{ \zeta'(1+ix)} {\zeta(1+ix)}dx$ it doesn't, in fact, give the desired value.

Can someone please tell me where I made the mistake? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you evaluate it ? Mathematica will have some problems with the branches of $\log \zeta(s)$.

Comment: @reuns it just tells me that the antiderivative is logζ(z), and gave me the values after inputting them in and their approximated form. And I mean, technically it isn't wrong. But the approximated form is nowhere near 2πi.

Comment: Plot $\Im(\log \zeta(s))$ on each segment, you should spot some where it is not continuous  (with some jumps), repair manually the values of $\Im(\log \zeta(s))$ at the edges of the segment so that it comes from a branch continuous on the segment.

Comment: The branch mentioned by @reuns occurs at $\Im(\log(\zeta(i\,x)))$ where $x\approx\Im\left(\rho_1\right)$.

Comment: Note that Mathematica gives a specific (principal) value of the argument, while here the argument is obtained by analytic continuation so moves between branches and the crux is finding those moves; a better bet is to use the real function $Z$ on the critical line and use standard  approximations of it to show the zero ar $14...$